# Can a C# application developed on Visual Studio 2010 run on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-10

My application is developed in C# on VS 2010 and Windows 7. I want to migrate the application on Windows 10 system.

Are there any patch fix available for the same? As I understand VS 2010 does not have support for Windows 10.

Comment: did you do any peculiar customisation such as changing interface manifest? it really depends on your application on how tightly it uses Windows APIs. if you only uses .Net APIs you should be fine after you recompiles to .Net 4.0 or 4.5 i think.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42541

above is the link for service 1 for windows10 try installing hope this solves your problem